# Can I generate compiled code at compiling time with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a legacy library that gets all the classes implementing `IFoo<T>`, instantiate them as singleon, and execute their `Execute` medhod.

I need to have a transient lifetime, and the implementation's constructor injected through DI and still make it compatible with the old system. But I cannot touch the legacy library.

So my idea is to create an interface `ISuperFoo<T>` with the same method that represents the transient lifetime, and at compile time generate `IFoo<T>` wrappers that instantiate a super-foo of T through our dependency injection framework in each execution, and that are picked up automatically by the legacy library.

I have been researching and it seems that it may be possible to do this through Roslyn, generating code at compile time like when state machines for async/await are created.

Found similar old questions, but wonder if now it is possible with https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeGeneration.Roslyn.BuildTime.

- [Can I use Roslyn for compile time code rewriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833954/can-i-use-roslyn-for-compile-time-code-rewriting)
- [Compile-time source code modification using Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328700/compile-time-source-code-modification-using-roslyn)

Basically I have:

```
interface IFoo<T>
{
    void Execute(T obj);
}
```

And at compile time I want to generate something like:

```
[EditorBrowsable(false)]
class FooWrapper<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    Container _container;

    public FooWrapper(Container container)
        => _container = container;

    public void Execute(T obj)
        => _container
             .GetInstance<ISuperFoo<T>>()
             .Execute(obj);
}
```

Container can be injected because it will be a singleton anyway.

Comment: BTW, `ServiceLocator` is not DI. You're not injecting anything. Yes, it's "kind of" an IoC, but actually it's an anti-pattern. To your question: you're probably looking for IL weaving like Fody or PostSharp.

Comment: Fair point. I just wanted to show a simplification of the problem. I will take a look at those thanks.

Comment: Can't you use something like Harmony or Fody? https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/wiki

Answer (score 0):

With Source Generators (currently in preview) you should be able to do this.

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/